# Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface

Tags: ros

I've benn trying to lanuch the demo_gazebo.launch to Moveit Setup Assistant, i dont know what happend ,my controller "arm_position_cotroller" can't spawn on controller manager,
i use "rosservice list" not find about controller manager,
rospack find controller_manager

```bash
/opt/ros/melodic/share/controller_manager
```

ros_controllers.ymal

```xml
arm_position_controller:
 type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
 joints:
   - joint_0
   - joint_1
   - joint_2
   - joint_3
   - joint_4
   - joint_5
 gains:
   joint_0:
     p: 1000
     d: 1
     i: 1
     i_clamp: 1
   joint_1:
     p: 1000
     d: 1
     i: 1
     i_clamp: 1
   joint_2:
     p: 1000
     d: 1
     i: 1
     i_clamp: 1
   joint_3:
     p: 1000
     d: 1
     i: 1
     i_clamp: 1
   joint_4:
     p: 1000
     d: 1
     i: 1
     i_clamp: 1
   joint_5:
     p: 1000
     d: 1
     i: 1
     i_clamp: 1
```

i have use gazebo plugin in srm_urdf.gazebo
this my code

```
git clone https://github.com/edwards414/ros_robot_arm.git -b master
```

I retrieve all articles releted to this issue and read ros_controll,controller_manager official documentation,I am still unable to find information about the issue in question